# Can't find gdk_property_change in PyGObject

Tags: python, gtk, pygobject

What is gdk_property_change binding in PyGobject? I've tried Gdk.property_changed, Gdk.Property.change etc. Function Gdk.property_get exist and everything else works great. My system is: Ubuntu 12.10, Python 3.2.3, PyGObject 3.4.0 and Gtk 3.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method is annotated with `(skip)`, which means it is not to be included in language bindings. (See [gdk_property_change](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/tree/gdk/gdkwindow.c#n11326) source code).

Here is the commit where that [marked unintrospectable constructs as (skip)](http://git.gnome.org/browse/gtk+/commit/gdk/gdkwindow.c?id=374e76a19dac87676995356f6daacb10f4bb6e36). The only explanation is that it is an 'unintrospectable' function. Perhaps because the `data` parameter can be any of `unsigned short *`, `unsigned char *`, or `unsigned long *`, cast to `unsigned char *`, and this was too difficult to deal with in language bindings.